# VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting

Tags: android, linux, valgrind, archlinux

I am integrating valgrind in AOSP for android marshmellow device.

```
+ Device Architecture- linux-x86
+ kernel Arch - 3.14.55-x86_64
+ valgrind version - valgrind-3.11.0.SVN.aosp
+ Host Architecture - linux-x86_64 (on this machine I am building image for device)
```

when I run command "valgrind ls -l" for testing. Its showing following error-:

```
    root@ET50T:/ # valgrind ls -l
    ==5197== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==5197== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==5197== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN.aosp and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==5197== Command: ls -l
    ==5197==
    --5197-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
    --5197-- si_code=80;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x82a4bb7c

    valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
    Killed by fatal signal

    host stacktrace:
    ==5197==    at 0x3816250E: ??? (in /system/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux)
    ==5197==    by 0x3807A2F3: ??? (in /system/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux)
    ==5197==    by 0x380B2B12: ??? (in /system/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux)
    ==5197==    by 0x380C987E: ??? (in /system/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux)

    sched status:
     running_tid=1

    Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 5197)
    ==5197==    at 0x400D4AB: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker)
    ==5197==    by 0x40115FE: __dl__start (in /system/bin/linker)
    ==5197==    by 0x1: ???


    Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
    It contains workarounds to several common problems.
    In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
    identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
    that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
    crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

    If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

    In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
    version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

same error is showing for all other tools(massif, hellgrind etc) also.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue with the integration. Can you try with other version of valgrind, let's say "valgrind-3.10.1"?

Not sure, this might resolve the issue, but just to check the error whatever you had seen has anything to do with valgrind tool version.

I hope the valgrind tool is cross compiled properly, please cross verify by running 'file valgrind' command on the command prompt.